# why should call std::move to pass s to constructor?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

```
//move the element
void StrVec::push_back(string &&s)
{
    chk_n_alloc();
    alloc.constructor(first_free++,std::move(s));
}
```

alloc is an object of allocator.
don't care about chk_n_alloc().
i just want to know **s** has already been a rvalue, why should call std::move to pass **s** to constructor? 
the code is from C++ primer 5th p545.

Comment: rvalue don't have name. `s` have a name, "s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky situation, `s` is passed as an rvalue reference, but when you give it a name it is therefore an lvalue so you have to move it, which as you may know is just a cast to an rvalue reference. This still means the argument has to be taken as an rvalue reference because that prevents non temporaries from being passed to it (unless they are moved)

Comment: The variable `s`does not (necessarily) have an address. But the expression `s` is an lvalue. One should point out that the type of an expression and the value category of an expression are two orthogonal concepts.